# Low internal memory, but high local and SD memory

Tags: external-sd, internal-storage, storage, insufficient-memory

I have a MID android tablet which has been giving me low storage messages during some downloads lately. But when I check, the local and SD have practically 3GB free. So, where is this data going, and how can i direct it to local or the SD?

I'm new with tablets; this is my first one.

the local and SD have 3 GB free combined(sd has 2 GB local has 1 GB), the system disk shows about half full (795 MB left) and I have no idea how to move my apps to the SD.

Comment: Do you mean *local and SD have practically 3GB free **each***, or both together? For "low storage" warnings, SD is mostly irrelevant. How much free space do you have on internal storage? Also, check the "Related" section of this question (in desktop browser, it's to the right) for other "low storage" questions. We had this issue quite often here, so your question probably is already answered.

Comment: I have system memory and internal memory, so "internal memory" is not all non-external memory

Comment: I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. Please check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which will answer your question.